# Whats the best approach for using sorcery(auth) with multiple user classes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, inheritance

I`m looking to create two models: trainer & client.

When signing up those two types of models share the basic auth info, such as email & password.

Thus I would like to use Sorcery to do the authentication for me, the gem creates a User model by default.

Searching through StackOverflow I understand I could use Single Table Inheritance, which most people find problematic.

Is there a better/simpler solution for those two types of users to share the basic auth info but be separate models which would contain their role specific data?

---

I`m sorry if I mixed things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of "role specific data" do your two users have?

I was in a very similar situation as you are in an app that I'm still developing. I chose to use a role based approach using CanCan.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :client_profile # or whatever a client has here
  has_one :trainer_profile # or whatever a trainer has here
end
```

Then, you would define your abilities

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # anonymous user
    if user.is? :trainer
      can :create, TrainerProfile
      # some other trainer specific roles here, like editing his/her profile
    elseif user.is? :client
      can :create, ClientProfile
      # some other client specific roles here, like editing his/her profile
    end
  end
end
```

Of course, the above code assumes an is? method on the `User` class to check the user role.

More info on CanCan can be found on the [CanCan wiki](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki), and also the [Railscast on CanCan](http://railscasts.com/episodes/192-authorization-with-cancan).

Comment: First of all Thank You for the response! The specific data is for example: a trainer has a specialization, max_clients, vanity_url etc. and a client might have a trainer_id, starting_weight, goal_weight etc. The relationship I`m looking to create between them is has_many and belongs_to. Hope this clarifies it a little bit. Later today I`ll sitdown and look into CanCan. However for my situation, I was thinking of building a custom auth system, so a trainer and client can create separate accounts etc. Not very DRY but might work. Let me know what you think, thanks again.

Comment: In that case, I wouldn't be too afraid of single table inheritance. Another suggestion, which might even be better, would be to create two models, `Trainer` and `Client`, that both call `authenticates_with_sorcery!`.